# Constant array size in class

Tags: c++, arrays, constants

I have a problem with creating an array in constructor.
Take a look at my code:

```
class foo
{
   private:
     const int size;
     double *tab;

   public:
     foo(int s);
};

foo::foo(int s):size(s)
{
   tab = new double[size][size];
}
```

Constructor can't create a new array because size of array is not a constant value... What's wrong with that? I bet it's really easy.

P.S.
I apologize for my poor english.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I declare a 2d array in C++ using new?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936687/how-do-i-declare-a-2d-array-in-c-using-new)

Comment: Yes, that's duplicate. I tried to find similar question, but I didn't notice this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tab` needs to be a double-pointer and you need to allocate the second dimension separately in a loop.

```
class foo
{
private:
    const int size;
    double **tab;

public:
    foo(int s);
    ~foo();
};

foo::foo(int s) : size(s)
{
    tab = new double*[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        tab[i] = new double[size];
}

foo::~foo()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        delete [] tab[i];
    delete [] tab;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Only the first dimension can be variable. Later ones must be compile-time constant.

> tab = new double[size][10]; // For example.

In this case, tab needs to be a pointer to an array:

> double (*tab)[10];

If you need the second dimension to also be variable, then you'll need to do something such as the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in C++ array dimensions need to be known at compile, except possibly the first dimension, which you can supply to the array `new[]` operator at runtime.

There are several ways to fix your code:

- Make `tab` a `vector<vector<double> >` and let C++ standard library worry about managing the memory,
- Make `tab` a `double**`, allocate `new double*[size]`, and then allocate the individual rows in a loop, or
- Keep `tab` a `double*`, allocate `new double[size*size]`, and do your own index translation when accessing the values.

I think the first approach is best, because it lets you avoid potential leaks without writing too much code:

```
class foo
{
   private:
     // const int size; <<== You don't need it - tab.size() gives you the size
     vector<vector<double>> tab;
   public:
     foo(int size);
};

foo::foo(int size)
:   tab( vector<vector<double> >(size, vector<double>(size, 0.0) ) )
{
}
```

If you do decide to go with the second or the third approach, remember to follow [*The Rule of Three*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29).

Comment: I think you mean "...possibly the first dimension...".

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate an array of array pointers first and then allocate each of the individual arrays.  For a more thorough discussion see [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21909/Introduction-to-dynamic-two-dimensional-arrays-in).  Here is your code as I would recommend.  Don't forget to include the destructor as I show here.

```
class foo
{
   private:
     const int size;
     double **tab;

   public:
     foo(int s);
     ~foo();
};

foo::foo(int s):size(s)
{
   tab = new double*[size];
   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
   {
       tab[i] = new double[size];
   }
}

foo::~foo()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        delete [] tab[i];
    }
    delete [] tab;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a std::vector of std::vector of double:

```
typedef std::vector< double > double_vector;
typedef std::vector< double_vector > double_2d_vector;
```

[snip]

```
double_2d_vector tab;
```

[snip]

```
foo::foo(int s) 
    : size(s), tab( s, double_vector( s, 0.0 ) )
{
}
```

[snip]

```
tab[ x ][ y ] = 4.57;
```

You really shouldn't be using raw pointers.

Comment: Although I agree with you why is tab declared as global but initialized within the foo constructor? That looks like a lazy example to me.

Comment: That's not complete code. It's just snippets to show how things would be declared.